# Printing the latitude and longitude of number of locations in a single page

Tags: javascript, latitude-longitude

I have a javascript.In it i have a code which displays the latitude and longitude of number of locations in pune.
The latitude and longitude gets displayed in an alertbox.

When i write it in a document.write() method it gives error.After that i used

```
"document.body.appendChild( document.createTextNode( latitude ) );
document.body.textContent = latitude;"
```

but it displays a single value.I want that all the latitude and longitude should be displayed in single page.Please guide me.

My code is here:

```
function myfun()
{
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="My Javascript";

  var geocoder=new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var i=0; 
  var address=new Array();
  address[0]="kothrud pune";
  address[1]="bharti vidyapeeth";

  for(i=0;i<address.length;i++)
  {
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address[i]}, function(results, status) 
      {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
        {
          var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
          var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
          //alert(latitude);
          //alert(longitude);
          //document.write(latitude);
          document.body.appendChild( document.createTextNode( latitude ) );
          document.body.textContent = latitude;
          //document.body.appendChild( document.createTextNode( longitude ) );
          //document.body.textContent = longitude;


        } 
      }); 
  }


}
```

Comment: add some code to your post to have a look at what you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include jquery, it's easier to use for manipulating  the DOM.
Get the div or other element you want to add the values to and use jQuerys html method to set the latitude and longitude values as text to the element.

```
$('#YourElementIdHere').html(latitude + ', ' + longitude);
```

Comment: jQuery is Javascript. The above as the equivalent of docuement.getElementById('YourElementHere').innerHTML = latitude + ', ' + longitude;

Answer (score 0):

You want to write the longitude and latitude to the screen? I would use jquery and create a div.

```
  <script>
  ....
  $("#Longlat").html(YourlongandLat);
  </script>
  ....
  <div id ="LongLat"></div>
```